# Expire Wordpress Posts at a certain time

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've a relatively simple Cron Job in my Wordpress site that runs a SQL query which expires a set of posts 7 days after they were first posted, the query in question works absolutely fine and has done for a long time, however, recently the need has arisen to make the posts expire at a certain time(12:01am) on the seventh day.

I don't claim to be a SQL expert, so have done a fair amount of digging around but I can't seem to make it work. i supplied the SQL query I have that works for the 7 days below:

```
global $wpdb, $post;

$expireAfter = "7";

$sql =  $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type = 'wpbb_job' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > %d",$expireAfter);'
```

I've found loads of resources for doing what i've already done, however none seem to tackle the time aspect of the problem. 
 Any help would be greatly appreciated, even just some recommendations on some articles i might've missed that tackle this issue.

Comment: did you check this plugin [Post Expirator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/)?

Comment: @flangofas yes, when we first built the site we looked at that, however because every post in the CPT needs to expire after the same amount of days regardless of when it was posted, adding in the fact that these posts are posted via an external service, this cron job and SQL query seemed like the best option

Comment: What if you just run the cron job every day at 12:01am with the same query then? Will this fix your issue?